# Extracting data from a SQL Server 2008 FILESTREAM field without using .NET

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

We have more than 200 gigs of data in sql server filestream. 
Can anyone suggest me is there any faster way to retrieve those files? 
Can we use "bcp" to get those files out?

Comment: I have no idea about this area myself, but MSDN has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878124.aspx) of using the OLE DB BCP API (not `bcp.exe`) to export filestream data; it might give you some ideas. But your real question isn't very clear: do you have some working .NET code that runs too slowly? If so you might want to post it and ask for ways to improve it. It also isn't clear if this is a one-time task or a recurring one, and exactly why you don't want to use .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, we know that using .Net is one option but it will be very fast if we use bcp utility. Also, this is a one time task.